# Lifting of certain $S^1$ valued maps

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

It's well-known that every path $s(t): I \to S^1$ has a lifting, i.e. mapping $\widetilde{s(t)}: I \to \mathbb{R}$, so that $e^{i\widetilde{s(t)}} = s(t)$. The main idea of constructing $\widetilde{s(t)}$ is the following:

1. Find by uniform continuity for $[0, t]$ such an $n$ that $|x-y| < 1/n \implies |s(x) - s(y)| < 1$.
2. Devide $[0, t]$ on $n$ parts.
3. For each part find $\phi_{n}$ is the angle between values in the left and right bounds of this interval.
4. Set $\widetilde{s(t)} = \alpha + \sum \phi_n$, where $\alpha$ is the initial value of the lifting.

There are two questions concerning this reasoning:

1. I dont's see any problems when trying to apply it to $s: S^1 \to
       S^1$, although in this case the statement is wrong.
2. How to modify this proof to be used for $s: I \times I -> S^1$

Comment: If you apply this statement to closed path, you won't get closed path in $\mathbb R $. This is the reason why you cannot apply this argument to maps $s: S^1\to S^1$

Comment: The claim holds for $X\to S^1$ if $X$ is simply connected

Comment: You have written the argument vaguely with some incorrect notation. Instead of writing an interval $[0,t]$ with the variable $t$, you should be writing the interval $[0,1]$. Also, the angle $\phi_n$ needs to be more precisely defined: is it a clockwise angle? a counterclockwise angle? positive? negative?

Comment: When you work out a more precisely correct argument, you will begin to see why it simply does not work for domain $S^1$. What willl happen is that as you start at one point $p$ on the domain $S^1$ and work your way around the circle and back to the starting point $p$, you will get two expressions for $\widetilde{s(p)}$ which are not equal. So your map will not be well-defined.

Comment: Michael, Lee, thank you. I see now!

Comment: Hagen, do you mean that from a point where the map is already defined we can extend it to nearby points in the same way as described by connecting them with a path?